# Sitefinity warmup module not starting after schedule app pool restart

Tags: .net, sitefinity, iis-8.5

I've enabled the Sitefinity Warmup module to start when IIS app pool recycles. When I manually recycle the app pool the warmup module starts and warms up the pages properly.

When the app pool restarts at it's scheduled 3am time, the warmup module does not run.

Anyone run into this? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Application Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) - For IIS 8.5 it is built-in, so you can either configure forcing individual applications to reinitialize after an application pool recycle/server restart, or configure the applications to reinitialize after a soft reset (edits in web.config, etc).
In order to set up application warm-up after a recycle, you need to edit your %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config file and locate your  block. Edit the settings of the application you’d like to automatically initialize after a restart like this:

```
<add name="MyApplicationPoolName" autoStart="true" startMode="AlwaysRunning" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
```

Next, under the  block, configure the serverAutoStart property of your website like this:

```
<site name="MySiteName" id="#" serverAutoStart="true">
<application path="/" preloadEnabled="true" applicationPool=" MyApplicationPoolName ">
```

This way, even if you recycle your application pool on regular intervals or at a specific date/time, it will initialize automatically afterwards and initial load time will be normal for the first user that hits your website afterwards.

For more information:

- [Sitefinity performance boosters - keeping your pages warm](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/grisha-karanikolovs-blog/2012/07/09/sitefinity_performance_boosters_-_keeping_your_pages_warm)
- [Use IIS Application Initialization for keeping ASP.NET Apps alive](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/oct/02/use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive)